# Confused on multiplying binomial fractions with FOIL

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the horizontal asymptote of $$f(x)=5\frac{(x+5)(6x-1)}{(7-x)(8x+2)}$$

I am trying to foil the numerator and denominator so that I may begin finding the HA, but the A (5) has me confused in how to approach the problem.  I can't seem to find any place to explain what to do with the A term. If anyone has a formula I can follow to explain how to approach the problem I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No need to FOIL. Divide numerator and denominator  with $x^2,$ and let x go to infinity.

$$ 5 \dfrac{(x +5)(6x - 1)}{(7 - x)(8x + 2)} = \dfrac{5\,(1 +5/x)(6 - 1/x)}{(-1 +7/x)(8 + 2/x)} = \frac{30}{-8} = - 3.75 $$

Answer (score 1):

$5 \frac{(x +5)(6x - 1)}{(7 - x)(8x + 2)} = \frac{5[(x +5)(6x - 1)]}{(7 - x)(8x + 2)}$. Just use FOIL to  multiply the binomials in the numerator, then use the distributive law to multiply the resulting trinomial by 5.

Comment: Awesome, got -3.5 for the horizontal asymptote after following your advice. Thank you!

Comment: @Rollerball You're welcome! What you can do if you're satisfied with my answer is accept it by clicking the check mark to the left of the text; see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more info.

Comment: @Rollerball -3.5 isn't the correct horizontal asymptote, though; -3.75 is, as shown by Narasimham's answer. You might want to recheck your work.